# Viewport.el.mask does not appear at all in javascript, too fast?

Tags: javascript, extjs, openlayers, viewport, mask

I have that code as the 1st line of my saving function

```
window.viewport.el.mask('Saving...','saving');
```

It works fine for the delete function, as it takes longer to do. If I use a timeout I can see the mask correctly, but without timeout it simply saves.

The problem is that users can actually save twice or even more if they are fast. The mask is working nice with delete, so I was wondering if you had an idea of why it's not appearing correctly without a timeout?

Also, my timeout always freeze the page forever. I'm new to JavaScript and computer science. Thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one possibility would be to introduce a delay on the server but it is generally not a good idea. What I do in these cases is that I disable the save button when the form or grid I need to save is not dirty. So the sequence is as follows:

1. not dirty - button disabled
2. user edits, dirty - button enabled
3. user clicks save - request is sent to the server
4. success response returns from the server - button is disabled as now the form/grid is not dirty anymore

It doesn't matter how fast the the response comes, if the mask has a time to show or not, button cannot be clicked twice for the same "dirtiness".